# Der Nebensatz „dass“ und „das“

Tags: grammar, difference, conjunction, subordinate-clause

Einige meiner Freunde benutzen *das* anstelle von *dass* im Nebensatz, wie zum Beispiel:

> Ich wusste es, das du einen Topf voller Gold versteckt hast.

Ist es ein Dialekt oder Hochdeutsch?

Comment: I think this in on the level of people in English confusing they're, their, and there. In my German class we did a work sheet where we had to fix Mann and man, seid and seit and das and dass, so I think it's just a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, this is a very important grammar rule. It does not have anything to do with dialect or Hochdeutsch. It is an important rule.

> Ich denke, dass dies sehr wichtig ist.

Here you HAVE to use "dass" with two s because here a conjunction is used to connect those two sentence parts.

> Das Kind, das sehr klein ist, spielt.
> Das Kind, welches sehr klein ist, spielt.

Here you use "das" with one s because here you need an article referring to the child (Kind).

Remember this important rule:

**Everytime you are looking for the correct "das(s)" to use ask yourself whether you could replace it with "welches". If that is not possible, you have to use "dass".**

> DONT: Ich denke, welches dies sehr wichtig ist.
>
> DO: Ich denke, dass dies sehr wichtig ist.

More on this topic [here](http://www.das-dass.de/).

Comment: Why would you consider a rule that only affects spelling important?

Comment: In spelling, yes.